# The notion of a differential on surfaces

Tags: differential-geometry

I just started to wrap my head around some differential geometry, and some things are really not clear to me. Suppose we have a surface $\vec{x}=\vec{x}(u,v) \in \mathbb{R}^3$ parametrized by $u$ and $v$. Most books I read so far introduce a notion of a differential that I seem to be unfamiliar with.

For example, do Carmo writes that by definition of the differential it follows that $d\vec{x}_q(\vec{e_1})=\left(\frac{\partial x}{\partial u},\frac{\partial y}{\partial u},\frac{\partial z}{\partial u}\right)$,
where $\vec{e_1}$ points along lines of $v=const.$

I know the differential as $d\vec{x}_q(\vec{e_1})=\frac{d}{dt}\vec{x}(\vec{q}+t\vec{e_1})|_{t=0}$.

Is the latter really used by do Carmo and others? Or is it some different definition? Because intuitively the two expressions are equivalent, since we just look for the projection of the derivative along constant v. If these notions are the same, how can I derive the first expression from the latter? I tried computing, but I am not really sure how to evaluate the derivative.

Help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to Carmo's definition, $d{\vec x}_q(w)=\frac{d}{dt}\vec x(\alpha(t))|_{t=0}$ where $\alpha$ is any differentiable curve in the domain of $\vec x=(x,y,z)$ such that $\alpha(0)=q$ and $\alpha'(0)=w$. You can take, for example, $\alpha(t)=q+tw$ as in the definition that you know.

The fact that the said definition does not depend on the choice of $\alpha$ is proved in the Appendix to Chapter 2 (see Proposition 7, p. 129), which follows from the equality

$$d\vec x_{\alpha(0)}(\alpha'(0))=\begin{bmatrix}\displaystyle\frac{\partial x}{\partial u}(\alpha(0)) & \displaystyle\frac{\partial x}{\partial v}(\alpha(0))\\
\displaystyle\frac{\partial y}{\partial u}(\alpha(0)) & \displaystyle\frac{\partial y}{\partial v}(\alpha(0))\\
\displaystyle\frac{\partial z}{\partial u}(\alpha(0)) & \displaystyle\frac{\partial z}{\partial v}(\alpha(0))
\end{bmatrix}
\alpha'(0)
$$

Taking $w=e_1$, we obtain

$$d\vec x_q(e_1)=\begin{bmatrix}\displaystyle\frac{\partial x}{\partial u}(q) & \displaystyle\frac{\partial x}{\partial v}(q)\\
\displaystyle\frac{\partial y}{\partial u}(q) & \displaystyle\frac{\partial y}{\partial v}(q)\\
\displaystyle\frac{\partial z}{\partial u}(q) & \displaystyle\frac{\partial z}{\partial v}(q)
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
1\\
0
\end{bmatrix}=\left(\frac{\partial x}{\partial u}(e_1),\frac{\partial y}{\partial u}(e_1),\frac{\partial z}{\partial u}(e_1)\right)
$$
as you want.

Answer (score 0):

Jänich "Vector Analysis" should contain three different definitions of differentiability proven as equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you meant $\vec x = (x(u,v),y(u,v),z(u,v))$.

Maintaining v constant would create a 3d trace on the surface.
Differentiating for u would provide a direction of travel along the 3d trace. The direction is positive (unambiguous) because of du. This is what you have written for $d\vec{x_q}$

On the second definition you differentiate for t along the same direction where v is constant, while $\vec q$ represents the point on the surface- also on the 3d trace where you intend to find the direction of travel.

The two definitions are equivalent.